# How to Configure Zend Router to Lookup a List of Controllers

Tags: zend-framework, url-routing

I have several controllers which I want to match with the usual router pattern.  These include: users, organisations, products.  They should be accessible via, for example:

- `/users/login`
- `/users/edit`
- `/organisations/edit`
- `/organisations/add`
- `/products/view`
- etc...

If the first segment of the URI does not match a controller name, then I want to assume it is the name of an organisation.  It should then call the browse controller, with the organisation name as a user parameter.

I can see how to satisfy the second part of the problem, i.e. calling the browse controller.  (I will simply create and register a new `Zend_Controller_Router_Route()`).

How can I get the first part working though?, ie. how can I configure a route to lookup a list of controllers?

The only solution I can think of is to register a static route for each controller, however I'm not sure I can pass user parameters this way.  Also, it would mean creating a large number of routes...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way I could think of now, is to first collect all your controller names and exclude them in your rule like this.

```
(!users|!products).*
```